# How do I compare FieldInfo's values of instances?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, fieldinfo

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myClass instance1 = new myClass();
        myClass instance2 = new myClass();
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(myClass).GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields) if (field.GetValue(instance2) == field.GetValue(instance1)) Text = "Yes";           
    }
}

class myClass
{
    public bool b = false;
    public int i = 2;
}
```

Never returns "Yes".

EDIT: *Without* knowing beforehand what the types will be. So I can't have: `(bool)field.GetValue(instance1)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `==`, which will be comparing the boxed values for any field where the type is a value type. Each time a value is boxed, it will create a new object, so `==` will never work like that. Use `object.Equals` instead:

```
 foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
 {
     if (object.Equals(field.GetValue(instance2), field.GetValue(instance1))
     {
         Text = "Yes";
     }
 }
```

(Using the static method here means it'll work even if the values are `null`.)

Comment: +1 Thanks. But I don't understand your comment about the static method. Do you mean as opposed to `field.GetValue(instance2).Equals(field.GetValue(instance1))`?

Comment: @ispiro: Yes - that will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `field.GetValue(instance2)` returns null - whereas the static method won't.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the `address` of the two objects returned by FieldInfo.GetValue and since those addresses in memory are different, the `==` is never true.

try replacing the `if` with this:

```
if (field.GetValue(instance2).Equals(field.GetValue(instance1)))
```

Comment: as Jon suggested above, better to use object.Equals to avoid problems when the first FieldInfo.GetValue returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Because *field.GetValue(instance1)* returns a "boxed" (object) version of the value, hence calling `==` you are only comparing two different references.

Try instead calling:

```
field.GetValue(instance2).Equals(field.GetValue(instance1))
```